# JTextField hangs on GUI update via X11 forwarding

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, freeze, x11-forwarding

I have a Swing GUI that allows a user to add JTextFields to the GUI as needed.  When I run this locally on the console (on ubuntu), everything works fine..  When I run the GUI from Cygwin on a Windows box using X11 forwarding, everything starts out fine, but when I click the "add" button to put a new JTextField on the GUI, the text field shows up as expected, but I can't click in it or modify it, etc., for a long time.  In fact, I can't click in the original text fields either..  After a little more than 30 seconds, the text fields come back to life and work normally until I click "add" again.

I've included a SSCCE below that demonstrates the problem.  Again, this only seems to happen when running with X11-forwarding, and if I run on the Ubuntu console directly, it works as expected, so I'm not sure if this will be reproduce-able for everyone else.

One last piece of information - in my real program, clicking the add button causes a JComboBox and two JTextFields to be added.  The combo box is responsive right away, but all text fields on the GUI (new ones and old ones too) are not.

HmmFrame.java:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class HmmFrame extends JFrame
{
  ArrayList< JTextField > fields;
  JPanel mainPan;
  JButton addButton;

  HmmFrame()
  {
    super("Hmmm");
    JTextField curField;

    fields = new ArrayList< JTextField >();

    setLayout(new FlowLayout());

    mainPan = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
    this.add(mainPan);

    addButton = new JButton("Add");
    addButton.addActionListener(new HmmListener());
    this.add(addButton);

    curField = new JTextField("Try");

    fields.add(curField);
    updateGUI();

    setVisible(true);
  }

  public void updateGUI()
  {
    mainPan.removeAll();
    for (JTextField curField : fields)
    {
      mainPan.add(curField);
    }
    pack();
  }

  public class HmmListener implements ActionListener
  {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actEv)
    {
      JTextField curField;

      curField = new JTextField("New One" + fields.size());
      fields.add(curField);
      updateGUI();
    }
  }
}
```

Hmm.java (driver)

```
public class Hmm
{
  public static void main(String [] args)
  {
    HmmFrame hmmFrame;

    hmmFrame = new HmmFrame();
  }
}
```

Comment: Couldn't reproduce it, sorry. You may try the "adding" operation on a swingworker thread. That may possibly solve the problem but I'm not sure if that even has anything to do with your problem. This is what I'm referring to, just in case: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html

Comment: +1 for SSCCE, notice for real code on any enviroment to use [Initial Thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html)

Comment: See also [*Initial Threads*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html).

Comment: So you are running X11 through ssh, like `ssh -X etc...`?

Comment: Yes, exactly..  I'm on a local network.  In Windows I start Cygwin, start Xwindows, bring up a terminal, xhost +, ssh -X myUbuntuMachine, run the program on the Ubuntu machine, it displays within cygwin, but it acts as described.  Everything acts normal when I turn around and run on the Ubuntu console directly.